# How to use addEventListener() , querySelectorAll and getElementsByClassName for popup box

Tags: javascript

I would like to put a popup box on my website which have same ID. Those pop up boxes should be display after I clicked button. Those buttons have same Id.

my script code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get modal element
var modal = document.querySelectorAll('.simpleModal');
// Get open modal button
var modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.modalBtn');
// Get close button
var closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.closeBtn')[0];

for (var i = 0; i < modalBtn.length; i++) {
       modalBtn[i].addEventListener('click', openModal);
        // Listen for close click
       closeBtn[i].addEventListener('click', closeModal);
       window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);
    }

function openModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Function to close modal
function closeModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Function to close modal if outside click
function outsideClick(e){
  if(e.target == modal){
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

My HTML code is below I mentioned This code using derived the data from database.

```
<?php echo"<a href='single.php'><img title=' ' alt=' ' src='images/$row2[pic]'></a>
            <p>Cookware</p>
            <h4>$ $row2[price] <span>$45.00</span></h4>"?>
        </div>

        <?php echo"
        <button  class='modalBtn button'>Details</button>
          <div class='simpleModal modal'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
              <div class='modal-header'>
                  <span class='closeBtn'>&times;</span>
                 <h2>Modal Header</h2>
              </div>
              <div class='modal-body'>
                <p>$row2[name]</p>
                <p>$row2[description]</p>
              </div>
              <div class='modal-footer'>
                <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>"?>
```

My HTML code

```
<div class="agile_top_brands_grids">                      
    <div class="col-md-4 top_brand_left">
        <div class="hover14 column">
            <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid">
                <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid_pos">
                    <img src="images/offer.png" alt=" " class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid1">
                    <figure>
                        <div class="snipcart-item block">
                            <div class="snipcart-thumb">
                                <a href='single.php'><img title=' ' alt=' ' src='images/c.png'></a>
                                <p>Cookware</p>
                                <h4>452<span>$45.00</span></h4>"?>
                            </div>

                            <button id='modalBtn'  class=' button'>Details</button>
                              <div id='simpleModal'  class=' modal'>
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                  <div class='modal-header'>
                                      <span class='closeBtn'>&times;</span>
                                     <h2>Modal Header</h2>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body'>
                                    <p>biscuit</p>
                                    <p>tasty food</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <button id='modalBtn' class=' button'>Details</button>
                              <div id='simpleModal' class=' modal'>
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                  <div class='modal-header'>
                                      <span class='closeBtn'>&times;</span>
                                     <h2>Modal Header</h2>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body'>
                                    <p>biscuit</p>
                                    <p>tasty food</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <button id='modalBtn' class=' button'>Details</button>
                              <div id='simpleModal' class=' modal'>
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                  <div class='modal-header'>
                                      <span class='closeBtn'>&times;</span>
                                     <h2>Modal Header</h2>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body'>
                                    <p>biscuit</p>
                                    <p>tasty food</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <button id='modalBtn' class=' button'>Details</button>
                              <div id='simpleModal' class='modal'>
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                  <div class='modal-header'>
                                      <span class='closeBtn'>&times;</span>
                                     <h2>Modal Header</h2>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body'>
                                    <p>biscuit</p>
                                    <p>tasty food</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <button  id'modalBtn' class=' button'>Details</button>
                              <div id='simpleModal' class=' modal'>
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                  <div class='modal-header'>
                                      <span class='closeBtn'>&times;</span>
                                     <h2>Modal Header</h2>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body'>
                                    <p>biscuit</p>
                                    <p>tasty food</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>

                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

When you click on the button it gets the [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) which is the modal in your case and displays that.

When you click on close it gets the modal by traversing the parents, and hides it.

When you click on the window it checks if the click is from inside the modal and if not hides.

```js
var modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.modalBtn');
var closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.closeBtn');

for (var i = 0; i < modalBtn.length; i++) {
  modalBtn[i].addEventListener('click', openModal);
  // Listen for close click
  closeBtn[i].addEventListener('click', closeModal);
  window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);
}

function getModal(child) {
  var modal = child.parentNode;

  while (modal && modal.className && !modal.className.includes("simpleModal")) {
    modal = modal.parentNode;
  }
  return modal;
}

function openModal() {
  var modal = this.nextElementSibling;

  if (modal && modal.className.includes("simpleModal")) {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

// Function to close modal
function closeModal() {
  var modal = getModal(this);
  if (modal)
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Function to close modal if outside click
function outsideClick(e) {
  if (e.target && !e.target.className.includes("simpleModal") &&
    !getModal(e.target)) {
    e.target.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class='modalBtn button'>Details</button>
<div class='simpleModal modal'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
      <span class='closeBtn'>&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      <p>$row2[name]</p>
      <p>$row2[description]</p>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-footer'>
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing Thanks for your help sir

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

`var modal = document.querySelectorAll('.simpleModal');`

modal is a NodeList, not an element. If you want to select the single `.simpleModal` then use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`.

Define `modal` like this:

`var modal = document.querySelector('.simpleModal');`

(you can also do the same thing for closeBtn - avoid `querySelectorAll` when you only want to select a single element, use plain `querySelector` instead)

Comment: Thank you for reply sir.I have many buttons which has same Id.each button should be show pop up box when it click.

Comment: Multiple elements with the same ID is invalid HTML, but I don't see any elements with any ID in the first place in your code.

Comment: I specified into HTML code. I derived item list from database. those lists display with button

Comment: You posted PHP code, but there still aren't any `id` attributes anywhere in there. Feel free to post a fuller example of your HTML (not PHP) to illustrate your issue

Comment: Looks like you have multiple #modalBtn - multiple elements with the same ID is invalid HTML. If you want to target multiple elements with shared characteristics, use a `class` instead.

Comment: If you don't mind please explain more sir.I confused. I already specified as class also but it won't work